# How to give a program an additional name/label for search?

Tags: xfce, search, .desktop

I am starting a lot of programs via the [synapse launcher](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project). For convenience, I'd like to give a program an *additional* name/label/tag/whatever, such as "XXYYZZ".

Is this possible (on XFCE)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Synapse but assuming it launches applications from your `PATH`, you should be able to create symlinks like so:

```
$ echo $PATH # check that ~/bin is in the PATH
...:/home/<user>/bin:...
$ which ls # check where the target program is located
/usr/bin/ls
$ ln -s /usr/bin/ls ~/bin/myls # create a symlink
$ myls # use the new name for the target program
... ls output follows ...
```

I guess then Synapse would also find it.